# How to combine two collections in Mongoose and sort them using createdDate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing application using MEAN.js in which I have two documents as below:

```
 var RingtoneSchema = new Schema({
      language: {
            label: String,
            code : String
        },
        deliver:{
            type:Boolean,
            default:false
        },
        artists: [RingtoneArtist],
        digital_booklet:{
           title: {
              type: String,
              trim:true

           },
          copyright:{
              type: String,
              trim:true

          }
        }
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: 'Please fill Album title',
            trim: true
        },
        created: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    });


    var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
      language: {
            label: String,
            code : String
        },
        deliver:{
            type:Boolean,
            default:false
        },
        artists: [artist],
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: 'Please fill Album title',
            trim: true
        },
    created: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        });
```

I want to get all the records from both schema and order them by created date to display them in client side. I don't know how to do this using mongoose.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb itself is not relational database and any kind of "join" operation is not possible. I see two ways to go:

1. Easy way, but not the best way:
   If you, say,  need to show 30 items on a page you need:

   - Load 30 items from Ringtone, load 30 items from AlbumSchema
   - Put them together in one array
   - Do final sort in memory.

Downside of this approach is you need to load more data into memory than needed and also perform in memory sort manually.

2. A better way. If you need to show data from two collections it can be a good sign to have one collection instead if two. Your two collections schema looks very similar. Later you can use [sparse indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) to optimize queries which require only one of two entities.

Implementation details if you pick first way: you can load data from two queries in parallel using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or using [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and do final in memory sort using [underscore](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Hope this helps!